# Move Div with window size change and other div is blocked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my custInfoDiv float left when the window is under 420px ***and*** the rightNav (right navigation bar) is displayed in block.

Right now I cannot figure out what is wrong, I do not have a console error, maybe it's something simple that I missed.

for some reason the snippet isn't working properly either... colors and correct css styling aren't showing up, but that is not what is causing the actual problem.

```js
// right nav
      const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
      const rightNav = document.getElementById('rightNav');
      const searchNav = document.getElementById('searchNav');

      toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (rightNav.style.display === 'none') {
          rightNav.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          rightNav.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });


// modal
      const notesTab = document.getElementById('notesTab');
      const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
      const close = document.getElementById('close');

      notesTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.style.display = "block";
      });

      close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      });

      window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      });

// div
      const custInfoDiv = document.getElementById('custInfoDiv');
      const mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 420px)");

     
      if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 420px)").matches & (rightNav.style.display = "block")) {
        custInfoDiv.style.float = "left";
      }
```

```css
table {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      h4 {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
      }
      #custInfoDiv {
        width: 220px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      @media (max-width: 420px) {

      }

      /* modal */
      .modal {
          color: white;
          position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
          z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
          padding-top: 200px; /* Location of the box */
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%; /* Full width */
          height: 100%; /* Full height */
          overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
          background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* background color for everthing behind div like body */
      }
      #close {
        float: right;
        margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
      }
      #notes {
        background-color: #595959; /* background color for content. */
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #3b3b3b;
        height: 100px;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      


// main
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

// Variables
$opensans: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;


// Resets

// Main Elements

body {
  font-family: $opensans;
  background-color: #5790ff;
}
#nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #797979;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #5b5b5b;
}
  #nav h3 {
   margin: 0;
  }
  #nav ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #nav li {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  #toggle {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #494949;
    border: 1px solid #494949;
  }

#rightNav {
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #494949;
  border-left: 5px solid #2b2b2b;
}
#rightNav ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#rightNav ul li{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

#typeSearch {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
#addCust {
  color: white;
  background-color: #494949;
  border: 2px solid #494949;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 630px) {
  #rightNav {
    display: block;
  }

  #searchNav, #navList {
    display: none;
  }

  #toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}


// Misc
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>hardwareapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.min.css.map">

  </head>
  
  <body>
    <nav id="nav">
      <h3>Customer</h3>

      <div id="navList">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Link</li>
          <li>Disabled</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="searchNav" style="position: fixed; right: 5%;">
        <input type="text" placholder="search"></input>
        <button type="button">search</button>
      </div>
      <div id="toggle" style="position: fixed; right: 5%;">
        <button id="toggle" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <br>
    </br>

    <div id="rightNav">
      <br>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Disabled</li>
        <li id="notesTab">Notes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="modal" style=" display: none;">
      <div id="notes">
        <i id="close" class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h4>Notes</h4>

      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="custInfoDiv">
      <h3>Someone</h3>

      <h4>Info</h4>
      <table style="background-color: #fff;">
        <tr>
          <th>Phone:</th>
          <td>903-123-4567</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Cell:</th>
          <td>903-222-3333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Email:</th>
          <td>someone@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Location:</th>
          <td>&#160;somewhere</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <h4>IP's</h4>
      <table style="background-color: #fff;">
        <tr>
          <th>Public Ip:</th>
          <td>10.10.10.122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Server Ip:</th>
          <td>10.10.10.120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>impi</th>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <h4>Firewall</h4>
      <table style="background-color: #fff;">
        <tr>
          <th>Model:</th>
          <td>something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>username:</th>
          <td>blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>password:</th>
          <td>blah blah</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <h4>Prosperity V</h4>
      <table style="background-color: #fff;">
        <tr>
          <th>Prosperity Version</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3.0</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <br>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8">    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your intention. `custInfoDiv` is already on the left at any window size. You wish the `rightNav` to also be on the left side?

Comment: @jfeferman I removed the code that was making it do that, but also, that code was supposed to float the div left only when the right nav is blocked, but it was floating left no matter what.